# How to export DWG from RVT file with Forge Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api, autodesk-designautomation

I am still new to Forge Development and followed all samples in the https://learnforge.autodesk.io.
What I want to achieve is export DWG from a RVT file. I did and achieved this in IExternalDBApplication with local Revit.exe. When I try to this on FORGE, I get this error:

> 湥整楲杮映湩獩偨慬批捡⁫⸮搠獥牴祯洠偟慬批捡卫慴整਍਍潣瑮湩極杮映湩獩偨慬批捡⁫⸮搠獥牴祯挠污卬牴慥⡭ഩഊ攊楸整⁤楦楮桳汐祡慢正਍਍RESULT: Failure - Result of running user app is failure

This is the result
https://drive.google.com/open?id=12vzbErYgTGB8uLlDtoExAOZLEw87VPJtbDBlr19IX44

App can be found here https://sheetexporter.herokuapp.com/

**I am trying input a *.RVT file and get a *.zip file with exported dwgs.
I set zip=true in output**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks for all help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It needs permission to access https://drive.google.com/open?id=12vzbErYgTGB8uLlDtoExAOZLEw87VPJtbDBlr19IX44.

Could you provide report.log and how your activity is defined? Thanks

Comment: [DesignAutomation.cs]https://github.com/lSelectral/forgeSheetExporter/blob/master/forgeSheetExporter/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs This is the link to DesignAutomationClass.
Also, I gave you access to the text file

Comment: Thanks, I can see the report in above link now. From the log, the job currently just fails during the running. I check your addin code: (https://github.com/lSelectral/forgeSheetExporter/blob/fde966d28c54b7d2e995eb72396c90eeaf3161f1/sheetExporterRevit/Command.cs#L66)

should it be "doc.Export(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "//exportedDwgs", "resutl.dwg", views, dwgOptions);"?

Comment: I fixed that part in a new clean repo https://github.com/lSelectral/sheetExporterv2.
But it still isn't working. I followed this blog to https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/how-generate-dynamic-number-output-design-automation-revit-v3. What I am doing wrong. Even If I remove export part completely it says user app error. I am creating new directory and exporting there. Can you look at https://github.com/lSelectral/sheetExporterv2/blob/master/forgeSheetExporter/Controllers/DesignAutomationController.cs this class, if somethings wrong. Thanks for any help.

Comment: From the log I can find, the job still fails when running the addin, I saw some problems in the [code](https://github.com/lSelectral/sheetExporterv2/blob/1fb37f9fdcd10016d66bc20581256860f2348b61/sheetExporterRevit/Command.cs#L54-L59)

1. The viewset to be exported must contain at least one valid view.
2. All the views must be printable for the Export to succeed. It can be assured by checking the CanBePrinted property of each view.

Please refer the Revit API doc [here](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2020/44ee91ff-c9f3-7df5-b8c0-81c17ac75dc7.htm)

Comment: What the error you got after `removing export part completely`?

Comment: Also, can you change the [code](https://github.com/lSelectral/sheetExporterv2/blob/1fb37f9fdcd10016d66bc20581256860f2348b61/sheetExporterRevit/Command.cs#L82-L83) to be something like `Console.WriteLine(ee.Message);`, so we may see the  exception information in the report. By the way, it is much easier for us to diagnose the issue if report can be provided. Thanks!

Comment: Thank you so much for everything @Emma Zhu. But real problem was on forge side :(. I just create a new app and test the project with its id and secret, and it works fine now. Sorry again for wasting your time. Also thanks for everything you teach.

Comment: So the problem is related to your Forge App account? Could you please also check this blog https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/handling-developer-status-not-active-response to make sure your account is not expired. Any other Design Automation Revit related issue, please follow my blog and feel free to ask here, we will check:)

Comment: @SeLeCtRa, good to know it works now! But I am a little surprised that it is forge issue because our log shows job fails by running the addin, which means the job was accepted by Design Automation service successfully. Running an addin actually has nothing to do with forge app...anyway, you are welcome to drop any question  to us!

Comment: I forgot to tell you, what I realized is my addin had never run. Because if it was running and throw error, first thing I should see is should be "Design automation started". But it never runs. In every step there is writelog. I don't know what happened either. Thank you for everything @Emma Zhu and Zhong Wu